# Regex look ahead assertion

Tags: regex, r

I need a `regex` expert on this problem. It's linked to a SO question I've lost, where the data are the following:

```
x = c("IID:WE:G12D/V/A", "GH:SQ:p.R172W/G", "HH:WG:p.S122F/H")
```

I need to split each element of `x` to isolate the end part which can be consituted of `letter - slash - letter - .... slash - letter`.
What I want is to obtain these two vectors as output:

```
o1 = c("IID:WE:G12", "GH:SQ:p.R172", "HH:WG:p.S122")
o2 = c("D/V/A", "W/G", "F/H")
```

I have this solution for `o1`:

```
gsub('[A-Z]/.+','',x)
#[1] "IID:WE:G12"   "GH:SQ:p.R172" "HH:WG:p.S122"
```

Good. For `o2`, I tried to use assertion and particularly look-ahead assertion:

```
gsub('.+(?=[A-Z]/.+)','',x, perl=T)
#[1] "V/A" "W/G" "F/H"
```

But this is not the wanted result!

Any idea what is going wrong with the second regex?

Comment: linked to this: stackoverflow.com/questions/31532852/string-split-and-expand-the-vector-at-the-delimiter-r ? ;-)

Comment: I think this can help: [`gsub('.*?([^/](?:/[^/])+)$','\\1',x, perl=T)`](http://ideone.com/0PREfF)? Or `gsub('.*?([A-Z](?:/[A-Z])+)$','\\1',x, perl=T)`.

Comment: @CathG, yes, I found the solutions two long and most of all my quick limits on regex :)

Comment: so you're posting a question to answer another... fun... ;-)

Comment: That was not my intention at first! But the look ahead assertion seems nice to solve. @stribizhev you can post it as a solution even if I prefer to handle assertion!

Comment: this works: `gsub('[^/]+(?=[A-Z]/.+)','',x, perl=T)`... (so almost what you had except it didn't work because "\" is included in ".")

Comment: @CathG you can post the solution, I will accept it (sorry stribizhev) since it enables me to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following, very near to what you came up with, will work:

`gsub('[^/]+(?=[A-Z]/.+)','',x, perl=T)`

(Your line didn't work because you were asking for "any character", which includes "\")

Answer (score 3):

As a possible solution, you can use the following replacement:

```
gsub('.*?([^/](?:/[^/])+)$','\\1',x, perl=T)
```

Or (if there must be a letter):

```
gsub('.*?([A-Z](?:/[A-Z])+)$','\\1',x, perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/0PREfF)

- `.*?` - matches as few as possible characters other than a newline from the start
- `([^/](?:/[^/])+)` - a capturing group matching:

  - `[^/]` - a character other than `/` (or - if `[A-Z]` - any English uppercase character)
  - `(?:/[^/])+` - 1 or more sequences of `/` and a character other than `/` (or if you use `[A-Z]`, an uppercase letter).
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gsub('\\w\\/.*(\\/.*)?','',x)
```

Regex look ahead:

```
gsub('\\w(?=\\/).*','',x,perl=T)

gsub('.*\\d(?=\\w\\/)','',x, perl=T)  #For O2
```

Comment: I do not need a regex for `o1`.

Comment: I added regex look ahead.

Comment: I will repeat one more: I am looking for the o2 result.